# Page 404 not found but was working untill few times ago

Tags: php, api, http-status-code-404, slim

I have an php backend, with 3 classes that manage my little program api rest, i done the first event.php and the api rest works well, so i done user.php same thing all working, then i done login.php and now works, but also the other pages are in 404, not found i really cannot understand why, i cannot reach them anymore. Someone can have some idea?

i use slimapp framework so i have method like this:

```
$app->post("/user/add", function(Request $request, Response $response)
```

before the code perfectly worked but now after i did login page every other api not works anymore even if i delete new page.

Comment: i used composer firebase/php-jwt can be this? maybe he consider protect all pages now? may i need barer?

Comment: Did you do anything to the API?

Comment: I found the error, in the index.php i calling require for any .php but this was a big mistake, solved with required_once

Comment: answer yourself?